# How can OpenAI Gym's visualizations work within Docker?

Tags: opengl, docker

I'd like to get OpenAI Gym working with the rendered OpenGL visualizations within a docker container.

It's straightforward to get OpenAI Gym running within Docker. However, it's not immediately clear how to get the rendered environment to display in a window on my OS X laptop when you call `env.render()` on an OpenAI environment within the Docker container.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try sharing your X11 socket file with your container... That way your container can write to it and it will show on you machine:

Something like this:

```
docker run --privileged=true --rm \
    -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    ...
```